# When breeding animals, is it legal to feed them pills that increase sex drive?

Tags: united-states, animals, dog

Take this scenario: Owner A has dog A and has agreed with Owner B to breed dog B. However, dog A does not like dog B. To avoid missing this opportunity, owner A gives dog A medicine that increases sex drive for a higher chance of mating with dog B. Is this legal?

Comment: Is there some reason you think this might not be legal?  I struggle to imagine what law this would violate unless there is something unstated (i.e. the drug has some side effect that potentially constitutes animal cruelty or the owners want to register the resulting puppies with some organization whose bylaws prevent assisted reproduction)

Comment: Perhaps the drug needs to be given to dog B so tht dog A will "like" her.

Comment: I am not sure "drive" is quite the right word, but using hormones or reproductive system modulating drugs is very common in various forms of farming, dairy in particular.

Comment: @JustinCave Off-label usage of prescription medication might be one such reason.

Comment: @nick012000 In what jurisdiction is off-label usage of prescription drugs a crime, even in humans?

Answer (score 4):

While different countries around the world have laws against animal cruelty, I don't see how any of them would apply here.

If there are no harmful side effects, the drug is legally available for this purpose to the owner, and it is the animals owner agreeing to it or in this case even administering it themselves... that is perfectly legal.

Comment: I think the part 'drug is legally available to the owner' is where some restrictions can come in. To my knowledge Viagra is prescription only in most EU countries so even if you legally got it for yourself you couldn't legally use it for your dog. I don't know whether there are animal alternatives and whether these are over the counter or whether some restrictions apply.

Comment: @quarague You may be right, I never considered that dogs might share prescription only medicine with humans. I edited in "for this purpose" just to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are various products available that purport to do something like this, a number of which are a brew of natural ingredients. Sildenafil is in fact used for dogs, but "off-label" for heart and lung high blood pressure conditions, and that is a prescription drug (no indication that it works in dogs the way it works in humans). Ignoring the question of efficacy, any given product might be subject to FDA regulation, so you would have to read [here](https://www.fda.gov/animal-veterinary/products/approved-animal-drug-products-green-book) for the specific product.